# VB.net code for finding date of birth from NIC

Tags: vb.net

I used this following vb.net code for extract the date of birth from National Identity card of Sri Lanka. When I execute the code in Visual Studio 2005 it gives error.Error " name txtID not decalred".

```
Public Class frmSLNIC
    Dim StrID, Sex As String
    Dim intMonth = New Integer() {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
    Dim intIDNum As Integer
    Dim y, m, d, mo, da As Integer
    'Dim txtID As String


    Private Sub frmSLNIC_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblSex.Text = ""
        lblDate.Text = ""
        txtID.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShow_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click

        Dim days As Integer
        Dim dateLable As String
        If txtID.Text.Length = 9 Then
            intIDNum = Integer.Parse(txtID.Text)
            StrID = txtID.Text
            y = 1900 + CInt(StrID.Substring(0, 2))
            d = CInt(StrID.Substring(2, 3))
            If d > 500 Then
                d = d - 500
                Sex = "Female"
            Else
                Sex = "Male"
            End If
            days = d
            mo = 0
            da = 0
            If y Mod 4 = 0 Then '' Checking leap year
                intMonth(1) = 29
            Else
                intMonth(1) = 28
            End If
            For i As Integer = 0 To 12
                If days < intMonth(i) Then
                    mo = i + 1
                    da = days
                    i = 13
                Else
                    days = days - intMonth(i)
                End If
            Next
            dateLable = CStr(mo) + "/" + CStr(da) + "/" + CStr(y)
            lblSex.Text = Sex
            lblDate.Text = dateLable
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid NIC Number", "Error")
            Return
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtID_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtID.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 13 AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only")
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want this to use in VS 2005 and the what modification I have to do this please

Comment: You have `DIM txtID As String` commented out. Uncomment it (remove the single ' from in front of that line). Your code is also trying to use a `String` as a `TextBox` by reading it's `.Text` property, and a string doesn't have a `.Text` property. Make up your mind - are you using a string named TxtID or a TextBox named TxtID?

Comment: Its never too late to read [Ask] and take the [Tour].